# looking for Webnovel apocalypse story

Tags: story-identification

I remember that the apocalypse started with increased growth in plant and animal life and that the MC encountered a giant snake that was eating people, before the apocalypse properly started.

Comment: Was it LitRPG? Wuxia? Aliens? Just a regular apocalypse? Do you remember what caused it?

Comment: I know it wasn't LitRPG, Wuxia or Aliens and I don't think a cause was revealed.